# Retrieve not-logged User Details from Spring Security

Tags: java, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I know how to retrieve user details if he is logged on, using SecurityContextHolder.

```
// Some code

UserDetails userDetails =
 (UserDetails)SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
```

So, my question is:

Is it possible to retrieve information about not currently logged user, for example by User Id only?

And how can I update the information about users if they are currently offline?

Answer (score 0):

The one populating your `SecurityContext` is usually a `UserDetailsService`, which you have to implement yourself or you take one of the existing ones.

I'm not sure I fully understand your question, but in theory you can simply use your UserDetailsService (or the services it itself uses to load a user), to get all the details you want. So, if you have a JPAUserDetailsService, this will likely call a repository and there's nothing stopping you from using that repository yourself.

What exactly is it that you are trying to do?